# rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the following when trying a `rake db:migrate`

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also get a similar message when going to my localhost

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

My rails server and rails console won't work either

I've been trying a few things and this is what my gemfile currently looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise'


gem 'pg'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:
```

What is the problem? It seems that to access my postgres table locally I need some sort of password? My app works fine when it is run through Heroku. So I am just doing Heroku open and I can submit new links and posts as my app is intended but it won't work locally.

Comment: How did you install Postgres locally?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: For your local machine (under test and development) in database.yml you should change username to your logged in username. The rails generator makes it the same as the app name - this will not work. For production it does not matter as it is run on Heroku and they change that setting automatically when you deploy.

Comment: Thank you Andre, that is very helpful and answers my question. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: My pleasure, I have put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your local machine, under the `test` and `development` sections in `database.yml` you should change `username` to your logged in username. The rails generator makes it the same as the app name - this will not work. For production it does not matter as it is run on Heroku and they change that setting automatically when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You should have values for *username* and *password* according to any of the existing ones. You can check your users with `psql -d postgres` and then `\du`