# Can not migrate database on Sinatra "no password supplied" for postgresql?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

I am working on Ruby project using Sinatra.
So, I have already created the database.
But when I tried to migrate it, I got below error:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

So anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704025/rake-aborted-pgconnectionbad-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-tasks-top

Comment: not the same i dont have "database.yml" this file.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database.

Comment: are you  using sqlite?

Comment: Nope i am using postgresql and i am using another ruby file to connect the database.

Comment: @NullSoulException i got the solution now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What was your command? if you are using rake, make sure you have some sort of environment file that links this as your database and have a 
      :password => db.password,